# SystemVerilog: registering UVM test with the factory

Tags: class, factory, system-verilog, uvm

I am confused with the following SystemVerilog construct used for registering the UVM test with the factory:

```
class random_test extends uvm_test;
    `uvm_component_utils(random_test);
    ...
    function new (...
```

Here we have a definition of the class `random_test`, and inside of the definition we call a method whereas its argument is the class that is being defined.

Here are my questions:

1. Is `` `uvm_component_utils `` being called at time 0 even before any object was constructed out of random_test class?
2. How can we pass a class to `` `uvm_component_utils `` in that class definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`` `uvm_component_utils `` is not a method, it is a macro which is evaluated at compile time.

You can see what the macro does in the UVM source code. Take a look at `src/macros/uvm_object_defines.svh` within the UVM distribution.

Your example for class `random_test` will expand to something like this:

```
typedef uvm_component_registry #(random_test,"random_test") type_id;
static function type_id get_type();
  return type_id::get();
endfunction
virtual function uvm_object_wrapper get_object_type();
  return type_id::get();
endfunction   const static string type_name = "random_test";
virtual function string get_type_name ();
  return type_name;
endfunction
```

Answer (score -1):

I was studying UVM and building some tests and had the same error. After some time searching about i figure out a detail that is your code too.

in:

```
class random_test extends uvm_test;
`uvm_component_utils(random_test);
...
function new (...
```

We don't need the semicolon after `uvm_component_utils(random_test)

So, the correct code is:

```
class random_test extends uvm_test;
`uvm_component_utils(random_test)
...
function new (...
```

Best Regards